# Call recorder without server

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, call, record

I searched the web, and found that there is no call recorder which records calls directly, all the apps call through server and store and play.

Is there any clue, such that a call recorder without server can be made, which can record call when we call directly from our phone and not from any app.

Comment: Apple  would not accept this type of apps you need to work with jail break

Comment: There is no way to record call, could be possible with VOIP services, but normal phones can't be recorded, even if app developed any how then App store will reject such app.

Comment: @Hasya alright :( thank you for suggestion.

Comment: I have posted the answer below (as community wiki). If you believe this to be the answer, please accept it (or post your own copy and accept that). That will mark this question as answered; thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted an answer, paraphrased from [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42664615/call-recorder-without-server#comment72454969_42664615))*.

Apple would not accept this type of app, since you need to work with a jail-broken device.